# TCP connection response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have established a TCP connection and I receive a response but I am not able to access the response data.

This is my code:

```
        client.on('data', data => {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });

        client.on('end', () => {
            client.end();
            console.log('disconnected from server');
        });
```

my response data is the variable data that I can see in the console.log as a string.

Comment: The console log prints one array of bits that is visible and I know the format. I just want to reuse the data value to another variable but I am not able.

Comment: *reuse the data value to another variable* — what exactly does that mean? Where in the code you posted is any attempt made at copying the value?

Comment: Well i try something like this :

  client.on('data', data => {
            response = data; 
            console.log(data.toString());
        });

The purpose was use the response. But when i try to access the response is undefined since the client message is sent and runs the code and only in the end executes the console.log.

Comment: Right, but you wrote that you do see the value from `console.log()`.

Comment: Yes. I can see the value but the variable is undefined.

Comment: If you need to use the value, save it in a relatively global variable and then do the work you need to do in the "end" event handler.

Comment: The response is defined outside the class to be global. But nevertheless does not appear until the end is done. 

How can i do this : "need to do in the "end" event handler."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enclose the connection inside a promise and then manage the response in the end of the connection. This allow me to control the connection times and always catch the response in the end and the correct value of the response.